# Old Excel temp files appearing when copying folder (Google Drive)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, google-drive-file-stream

I use Google Drive on Windows 10.

I have a template folder in a Google Drive for Desktop (formerly file-stream) folder with an Excel spreadsheet in it.  I occasionally update this spreadsheet and give it a new version number, i.e. *Spreadsheetv1.23.xlsm.*

All files and folders are created inside Windows 10.  I've noticed recently when copying the template folder (via Windows File Explorer) that the copied version contains multiple temp files of the current and previous spreadsheet versions i.e. *~$spreadsheetv1.22.xlsm* , *~$spreadsheetv1.23.xlsm*  etc.

The source folder does not have these files visible in Google Drive or Windows Explorer (even if that latter has the *View>Hidden Items* checkbox ticked).

How do I display these temp files in the source folder so I can delete them?
(I can delete them in the copied folder no problem, but that's not a solution!)